# Custom variables for Mercurial possible?

Tags: mercurial

When I commit my changes I add a technical description to it. But for a changelog I need the information if the change is *relevant for our customer*. This information should be required to add as a developer.

I saw that can get a different log via

```
hg log --template 'author: {author}\n'
```

But as variables I can only use build in variables like `{author}`.

I want to use own variables that are also visible in html-view.

Is that possible?

Comment: If you store customer-id with changeset (you *have* to do it), you can filter changeset based on this data. HOW do you save customer-label now?

Comment: I see two possible solutions, you either store it in the changeset description in a machine-parseable format but it will be visible everywhere the description is visible. Or you can store it in the changeset extra, I don't think there is a in-core command or option to do it but you can do it with an extension and extract it later to generate the changelog.